# How to increase open area of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using the Navigation Drawer in my app. It works fine, but it opens only when I swipe from left border(1% - ~10% of whole screen). I want to increase this area to 1% - 70% of whole screen. I mean, I want to swipe to the right in center of screen and open Navigation Drawer. Its like in a Telegram App. Just check it. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Can you write something about these ways? I know nothing about them.

Comment: You can research some of these ways, a quick Google or stackoverflow search should give you everything you need. If you find something, try it, if it doesn't work post what you tried and we can go from there.